ROS2 Generating Odometry with GPS and IMU Data and Visualizing in RViz
I'm a new robot developer and I am learning ROS2, and I'm working on a project where I want to make a robot go straight to a specific area using GPS and IMU data. Since there won't be any obstacles around the robot, I don't need additional sensors like LIDAR or cameras. However, the biggest challenge I'm facing is that I can't generate odometry with GPS and IMU data, and I can't visualize this data in RViz.
Currently, I'm using GPS and IMU sensors to determine the robot's position and orientation. However, I'm struggling to convert this data into odometry and then visualize it using RViz. I need your help to figure out the steps to ensure the robot goes smoothly to a specific area without odometry.
I tried ekf with robot_localization but imu and gps data did not enter odometry. I tried to write it myself without success
ekf.yaml file:
# For parameter descriptions, please refer to the template parameter files for each node.

ekf_filter_node_odom:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    two_d_mode: true # Recommended to use 2d mode for nav2 in mostly planar environments
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false
    publish_tf: true

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link # the frame id used by the turtlebot's diff drive plugin
    world_frame: odom

    odom0: gps
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    imu0: imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  false,
                  false,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false  # If using a real robot you might want to set this to true, since usually absolute measurements from real imu's are not very accurate
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,  0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.5,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.1,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3]

ekf_filter_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    two_d_mode: true  # Recommended to use 2d mode for nav2 in mostly planar environments
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false
    publish_tf: true

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link # the frame id used by the turtlebot's diff drive plugin
    world_frame: map

    # odom0: gps
    # odom0_config: [false, false, false,
    #               false, false, false,
    #               true,  true,  true,
    #               false, false, true,
    #               false, false, false]
    # odom0_queue_size: 10
    # odom0_differential: false
    # odom0_relative: false

    odom0: gps
    odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    imu0: imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  false,
                  false,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false  # If using a real robot you might want to set this to true, since usually absolute measurements from real imu's are not very accurate
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1.0,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.5,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.1,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3]

navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0
    yaw_offset: 0.0
    zero_altitude: true
    broadcast_utm_transform: true
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: true
    wait_for_datum: false 

and launch.py file:
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
import launch_ros

def generate_launch_description():
   
    start_ekf_local = Node(
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='ekf_node',
        name='ekf_filter_node_odom',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/dual_ekf_navsat.yaml')],
        remappings=[('odometry/filtered', 'odometry/local')]  
        )
    
    start_ekf_global = Node(
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='ekf_node',
        name='ekf_filter_node_map',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/dual_ekf_navsat.yaml')],
        remappings=[('odometry/filtered', 'odometry/global')]
        )
    
    navsat_transform= Node(
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='navsat_transform_node',
        name='navsat_transform',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/dual_ekf_navsat.yaml')],
        remappings=[('gps/fix', 'gps')]
        )

    return LaunchDescription([
        start_ekf_local,
        start_ekf_global,
        navsat_transform
    ])

rqt-graph

You need to provide more specifics, such as what your code looks like that doesn't work. Using the robot_localization package is generally the correct solution here.

I tried robot_localization, I put the gps and imu into the ekf first and then I listened to the odometry data coming out of the ekf and I got no result.
rqt-graph

That means there is something wrong with your ekf setup. It's really impossible to say without seeing the actual roslaunch file/code.

I updated the article. Will this do? I collected external gps and imu data with ros bag. Then I wrote ekf.yaml file in the config file, then I added what I showed in launch.py to the launch file and ran it. I also added what I saw in rqt-graph as a visual.
